# Is the Webkit inspector (developer tools) a suitable replacement for Firebug yet?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, webkit, firebug, web-inspector

The Safari & Chrome developer tools (webkit inspector) seem to have become quite advanced. Although I'm very used to Firebug and rely on it for development, I'm really flirting with the idea of trying to just make a complete switch to Chrome (since I browse almost exclusively with it anyway) and just learn to get use to it's web developer tools.

It functions a little differently than Firebug, and I have noticed that you can easily modify values in the markup or CSS rules on the fly. So apart from any basic differences in the interface, has the webkit web inspector become a suitable replacement for firebug yet?

*NOTE I'm asking my question from the standpoint of a front end designer/developer doing primarily HTML & CSS work; I don't even really get into javascript much - yet.*

Comment: Readers of the future, note that as of today (July 2012, Chrome 20) Google Chrome is a terrific development tool and vastly superior to Firefox + Firebug.

Comment: Readers of the future: as of today (August 6 2013), Firebug is far superior than other rubbish development tools.

Comment: Readers of the future: as of today (February 13 2014), Firebug and firebug is STILL far superior than other rubbish development tools

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A big YES ;-) and even for javascript debugging.

Since Chrome 6 I never needed to switch back to firebug when debugging.

And profiling tools are simply **awesome**.

Comment: Big fan of webkit inspector and I love chrome too. I just wish chrome didn't use on average 50% more memory than firefox (at least on my computer) otherwise I never would have switched back to ff.